# Pythonet C# Exceptions not printed in Jupyter Notebook on Mac

Tags: python, c#, jupyter-notebook

I'm using pythonet to call functions from my C# project in Python. When I use Jupyter notebooks to call the C# functions, any errors result in the kernel hanging indefinitely, and no error message being printed. When I run the exact same code in a Python script in the terminal, I get the error message and the process terminates as expected. I wonder if this is OS related because my team members on Windows do not see this issue in their Jupyter notebooks.

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.6 with an M1 chip, VS 2022, Python 3.9.12, IPython 8.0.0, jupyter_client 7.4.9, jupyter_core 5.3.0, jupyter_server 2.5.0.

Here is my example C# project:

```
// Project HelloWorld
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class Adder
    {
        public int Add(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        { }
   }
}
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from clr_loader import get_coreclr
from pathlib import Path
from pythonnet import set_runtime
from os.path import abspath

# setting the path to my published project
libfolder = Path(abspath("")) / "lib"
set_runtime(get_coreclr(runtime_config=libfolder / "clr_runtime.json"))
import clr
clr.AddReference(str((libfolder / "HelloWorld").absolute()))

from MyLibrary import Adder

adder = Adder()
print(f"My C# Adder method: {adder.Add(3.2, 4)}") # adding a float instead of int will cause an error
```

When I run this in a Jupyter notebook, the kernel hangs and I don't get any output (I have to restart the kernel). When I run this in a Python script, I get the expected error message:

```
Python.Runtime.PythonException: an integer is required

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

System.ArgumentException: an integer is required in method Int32 Add(Int32, Int32)
 ---> Python.Runtime.PythonException: an integer is required
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (an integer is required in method Int32 Add(Int32, Int32))
 ---> System.ArgumentException: an integer is required in method Int32 Add(Int32, Int32)
 ---> Python.Runtime.PythonException: an integer is required
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/virgfrey/Projects/Hello World/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(f"My C# Adder method: {adder.Add(3.2,4)}")
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for Adder.Add: (<class 'float'>, <class 'int'>)
```

Note that when I call the function with correct arguments, it prints the expected output just fine in the Jupyter notebook. Only when there is an error the kernel hangs.

Comment: I know that [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) works in Jupyter. It may allow you to at least get the error message that the Jupyter users are missing. Demo for in a notebook is [here](https://notebook.community/minrk/wurlitzer/Demo).

Comment: Thanks! This uses ctypes though, I'm trying to make it work with pythonet.

Comment: Sorry, since it is Python-based, I think, I thought the approach may work or provide an idea how the approach could be made to work in your case.